# Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, redmine, saml

I'm using Redmine SAML authentication plugin to integrate redmine with my application inorder to enable Single Sign On(SSO) in redmine which made it possible for users to login with the same username and password. Following ruby and rails versions installed.

**ruby -v**: ruby 1.9.2p330 (2014-08-07 revision 47094) [x86_64-linux]

**rails -v**: Rails 3.2.19

**rake --version**:rake, version 10.4.2

Im getting following exception when application starting.

```
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

/home/chanuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
/home/chanuka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330/gems/passenger-4.0.57/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330/gems/passenger-4.0.57/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in `running_bundler'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330/gems/passenger-4.0.57/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330/gems/passenger-4.0.57/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330/gems/passenger-4.0.57/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330/gems/passenger-4.0.57/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330/gems/passenger-4.0.57/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'

Error ID d4b15bdd
```

Application root /opt/redmine/redmine-2.6.0

Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
production

I tried `bundle install rake` , `bundle update` but still doesn't work.

Comment: Whats in the `Gemfile`?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy Which part of the Gemfile I need to consider?

Answer (score 2):

Try packing the gems into vendor/bundle.

From inside your app directory type this:

```
# bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Comment: Thanks!  This solved it for me.  I tried all the other suggestions here and on many other related posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have many rake versions installed in your system

Uninstall all the rake version(s) and try to install your specified version manually and try 
again

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using rbenv for my ruby 2.2.0 install. I fixed it through trial and error.

I tried doing `gem install rake` but this didn't fix it. So I did:

```
gem uninstall rake
rbenv global 2.1.1
rbenv rehash
rbenv uninstall rake #this time gives error "rake is a default gem"
rbenv global 2.2.0
rbenv rehash
gem install rake
rails s #works this time
```

My expectation is that there was maybe a conflict somewhere in PATH or similar that was resolved with a complete remove

I've had that error with multi_json before. I fixed it by doing a manual install: `gem install multi_json`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, ran `gem uninstall rake` and then found out I was running 2 versions of rake. Simple prompt followed allowing me to uninstall the version I no longer wanted and keep version 10.4.2

Comment: Could elaborate more the solution you provide?